# esri google maps api - Create a single GPolyline from an array of features

Tags: google-maps-api, polyline-creation

I'm using the [esri google maps extension api](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/gmaps/help/google_start.htm)...

I have a **esri.arcgis.gmaps.FeatureSet()** 
(of type esriPolyline) containing an array of features (**esri.arcgis.gmaps.Feature()**).

Is there a simple way to create a single GPolyline from the array of features?

or since feature[i].geometry is a GPolyline, I guess I am asking is there a simple way to create a single GPolyline by joining/merging multiple GPolylines?

nb: The features returned from arcgis are not ordered... so I have to re-order the features before creating the GPolyline...

Comment: The link you provided now redirects to http://www.esri.com/landing-pages/products/google-lp/ so I am wondering whether this question (which has no accepted answer) be better of deleted along with those answers?

Answer (score 1):

I didnt get you.But to draw a polygon you can add edting toolbar.No need to go to these functions.Add diting toolbar like
map.Control.Editingtoolbar(vector_layer);

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kiran. However, I don't want to draw a polygon. I have an array of GPolylines that I would like to merge/union into a single GPolyline. Cheers, Michael.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each feature[i].geometry and call getVertices(i) on the GPolylines, building a new GPolyline from each vertex using insetVertex or the constructor, which will take an array of vertices.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GPolyline

Comment: Hi Guddie, thanks for the reply. I should have been more explicit in the original question... the problem is that the features are returned in no particular order from arcgis, therefore, I had to re-order the features manually (uurghh...) and then construct the polyline in the manner that you suggest... I was just hoping that there was a method that would do the joining/merging and work out the ordering... FYI - In the non-google arcgis api, the features are returned as ordered polylines/paths...)

cheers, Michael